# how do i make multiple circles decrease

Tags: python

im not sure how to make it view the code or images the proper way
if this code does the following

```
import turtle

turtle.penup()
for i in range(1, 500, 50):
    turtle.right(90)    # Face South
    turtle.forward(i)   # Move one radius
    turtle.right(270)   # Back to start heading
    turtle.pendown()    # Put the pen back down
    turtle.circle(i)    # Draw a circle
    turtle.penup()      # Pen up while we go home
    turtle.home()       # Head back to the start pos
```

[what this code above does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yghqm.png)

how do i change the code to do the following .i have tried changing the start, right etc. i want it to start from a set radius that i set and shrink so that when it gets to a certain radius it just stops [what i want it to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIHdW.png)

Answer (score 2):

Don't go home each time, go two radiuses down.

```
import turtle

turtle.penup()

for i in range(1, 500, 10):
    turtle.right(90)        # Face South
    turtle.forward(2 * i)   # Move two radiuses down
    turtle.right(270)       # Back to start heading
    turtle.pendown()        # Put the pen back down
    turtle.circle(i)        # Draw a circle
    turtle.penup()          # Pen up while we go home
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but how do i make it start with a wider circle and shrink to a smaller radius

Comment: for i in range(50, 1, -8):